# Change color of button in AlertDialog.Builder

Tags: android, android-studio-2.2

Given a function as

```
private void showInputDialog() {
    final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    final EditText input = new EditText(getActivity());
    input.setSingleLine();
    FrameLayout container = new FrameLayout(getActivity());
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new  FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.leftMargin= convertDpToPx(25);                                       //remember to scale correctly
    params.rightMargin= convertDpToPx(30);
    input.setLayoutParams(params);
    container.addView(input);
    alert.setTitle("Change City");
    alert.setMessage("Hey there, could not find the city you wanted. Please enter a new one:\n");
    alert.setView(container);
    alert.setPositiveButton("Go", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            changeCity(input.getText().toString());
        }
    });
    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    alert.show();
}
```

Now when I get this AlertDialog.Builder in my app, the button colors are green (default from Android 5), but the EditText color is Pink(R.color.coloraccent). How can I change the color of the buttons to pink?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: set the style in alerdialog.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try like this

```
alertDialog.show();
```

**Only after .show() was called.** 
try this snippet

```
//for negative side button
    alertDialog.getButton(dialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setTextColor(neededColor); 
//for positive side button
    alertDialog.getButton(dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setTextColor(neededColor);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can theme this. The buttons use the accentColor in your theme by default for textColor, as you noted, to change this you should:

Modify your app theme in res/values/styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.MyStyle</item>
</style>
```

And add your button style to theme the AlertDialog button

```
<style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.MyStyle">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

**Note**

This would affect all AlertDialogs and not just a single one. You can also create a new separate theme and add to the AlertDialog.Builder like `new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.MyAlertDialogTheme)`

Comment: This will not work since AlertDialog uses `?alertDialogTheme` of `AppTheme`. You'd have to override the alert dialog theme and the button style inside it.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a custom view to your alert window. creates a layout file named "my_custom_alert_window" then do like below:

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_custom_alert_window, null);
dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

Button btn = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.label_field);
btn.setBackgroundColor(....);
AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
alertDialog.show();
```

then you can change the background color of the button like the above