# How to change color of Button in Alert Dialog

Tags: android, message

Here my code for create Dialog,

```
builder.setMessage(msg).setNeutralButton("Dismiss",dialogClickListener)
                       .setPositiveButton("Edit", dialogClickListener)
                       .setNegativeButton("Delete", dialogClickListener).show();
```

Is it possible to display dismiss in blue color rather than red?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39930505/change-color-of-button-in-alertdialog-builder

Comment: The answer given below by Sheikh teach me about AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
The answer by Brahmy adigopula in original question just refers to AlertDialog.show  out of the blue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, create AlertDialog from builder:

```
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
```

Then you can find your button and change color:

```
dialog.show(); //Only after .show() was called
dialog.getButton(dialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setTextColor(your_color);
dialog.getButton(dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setTextColor(your_color);
dialog.getButton(dialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL).setTextColor(your_color);
```

Here you use next [method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextColor(int)):

```
void setTextColor (int color)
     Sets the text color for all the states (normal, selected, focused) to be this color.
Parameters
     color  int: A color value in the form 0xAARRGGBB. Do not pass a resource ID. To get a color value from a resource ID, call getColor.
```

Comment: Thank you, a little cryptic answer but it pointed me out to the right direction, now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it is possible, change color from style and you can define custom style for your dialog like below:

```
<style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog.Alert">
  <item name="android:colorPrimary">yourColorCode</item>
  <item name="android:colorAccent">yourColorCode</item>
</style>
```