# Change dialog button color

Tags: android, material-design, android-alertdialog, material-components-android, material-components

Is there any way how to change default dialog buttons colour, or do I need to do custom dialog for that?

This is my dialog:

```
private void removeItem(final int position) {
    /** Create dialog which ask if user is sure about delete name from list **/
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Delete player");
    builder.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    builder.setMessage("Do you want to delete player: \"" + mNameList.get(position).getText1() + "\"?")
            .setCancelable(false)

            /** If user click "ok" button, delete player from list and save changes **/
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    mNameList.remove(position);
                    mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
                    saveData();
                }
            })

            /** If user click "cancel" button, name won't delete from list **/
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                }
            });

    /** Create Dialog **/
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46397707/how-to-change-color-of-button-in-alert-dialog

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27965662/how-can-i-change-default-dialog-button-text-color-in-android-5

Comment: @Antti if my answer helped you or if it is correct according to your question, please, considere accepting it :)

Answer (score 34):

You can use the [**`MaterialAlertDialogBuilder`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Dialog.md) provided by the [Material Components library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) which allows the creation of a Material `AlertDialog`.

Just use:

```
   new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(MainActivity.this,
       R.style.MyThemeOverlay_MaterialComponents_MaterialAlertDialog)
              .setTitle("Dialog")
              .setMessage("Lorem ipsum dolor ....")
              .setPositiveButton("Ok", /* listener = */ null)
              .setNegativeButton("Cancel", /* listener = */ null)
              .show();
```

Then define your custom style, using the **`buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle`** and **`buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle`** attributes:

```
  <!-- Alert Dialog -->
  <style name="MyThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">
     <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/PositiveButtonStyle</item>
     <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/NegativeButtonStyle</item>
     <item name="buttonBarNeutralButtonStyle">....</item>
  </style>


  <style name="PositiveButtonStyle" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="backgroundTint">#00f</item>
  </style>

  <style name="NegativeButtonStyle" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/secondaryColor</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [Material 3](https://m3.material.io/components/dialogs/overview), there are new itens and Themes to style your dialogs:

#### Implementing dialog theming

Setting the theme attribute materialAlertDialogTheme to your custom ThemeOverlay will affect all dialogs.

In `res/values/themes.xml`:

```xml
<style name="Theme.App" parent="Theme.Material3.*">
  ...
  <item name="materialAlertDialogTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.App.MaterialAlertDialog</item>
</style>

<style name="ThemeOverlay.App.MaterialAlertDialog" parent="ThemeOverlay.Material3.MaterialAlertDialog">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/shrine_pink_100</item>
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/shrine_pink_100</item>
    <item name="colorSurface">@color/shrine_pink_light</item>
    <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/shrine_pink_900</item>
    <item name="alertDialogStyle">@style/MaterialAlertDialog.App</item>
    <item name="materialAlertDialogTitleTextStyle">@style/MaterialAlertDialog.App.Title.Text</item>
    <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/Widget.App.Button</item>
    <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/Widget.App.Button</item>
</style>
```

In `res/values/styles.xml`:

```xml
<style name="MaterialAlertDialog.App" parent="MaterialAlertDialog.Material3">
    <item name="shapeAppearance">@style/ShapeAppearance.App.MediumComponent</item>
    <item name="shapeAppearanceOverlay">@null</item>
</style>

<style name="MaterialAlertDialog.App.Title.Text" parent="MaterialAlertDialog.Material3.Title.Text">
     <item name="android:textColor">@color/shrine_pink_900</item>
</style>

  <style name="Widget.App.Button" parent="Widget.Material3.Button.TextButton.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/shrine_pink_900</item>
  </style>

<style name="ShapeAppearance.App.MediumComponent" parent="ShapeAppearance.Material3.MediumComponent">
    <item name="cornerFamily">cut</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">8dp</item>
</style>
```

Or if you want to change only one specific dialog, pass the `themeResId` to the constructor:

```kotlin
MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context,  R.style.ThemeOverlay_App_MaterialAlertDialog)
    ...
    .show()
```

Reference: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Dialog.md#theming-dialogs

Answer (score -1):

you can give `style` to your alert `dialog` like this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.AlertDialogStyle);
```

And you can write this style in `xml` file like this:

```
<style name="AlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:colorAccent">#f3f3f3</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#f3f3f3</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#f3f3f3</item>
</style>
```