# What is the font used in following Android Material dialog?

Tags: android, fonts, android-alertdialog, material-components-android, android-fonts

I want to know what is this font used for **CANCEL**, **DECLINE** and **ACCEPT** in the following material dialog.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font is [Roboto](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto) and you can check this guide about [Material Design's text sizes and styles](https://material.io/develop/web/guides/typography)

You can also check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57053520/change-dialog-button-color) about changing the dialog style programmatically with [MaterialAlertDialogBuilder](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Dialog.md)