# Android AlertDialog buttons: wrong text color

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have an app that I recently migrated to androidx.
I faced this problem: all Dialogs use primary color for buttons text color, but it should be secondary (or accent).
To fix this bug I created a style and applied it to every Dialog. However I suspect that there must be a better solution...
What could be the reason?

Comment: I think these two links will help you
<br> [First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46397707/how-to-change-color-of-button-in-alert-dialog) [Second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27965662/how-can-i-change-default-dialog-button-text-color-in-android-5)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I already found how to change the color. Instead, I would like to know why the default color is wrong. I think there could some issue with the libraries...